# Fabric.with Twitter causing crash with no reason

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric, twitterkit

I've updated my pods to the latest version of Fabric, Crashyltics and Twitter and now this line (the first line in my app) is crashing

```
 Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self], Twitter.self])
```

If I change it to remove Twitter the app does not crash on this line.

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

The crash has no information and is simply just a SIGABRT

*here are the versions of the relevant pods.*

- TwitterKit 3.1.1
- Crashlytics 3.8.6
- Fabric 1.6.13

Comment: can you share more details like exception, screenshot etc.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Twitter is no longer offered via Fabric, so I'd recommend migrating: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/fabric Since Twitter Kit 3 launched, you'd have a different init just for Twitter separate from the Fabric init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer was provided in a comment:

> Mike from Fabric here. Twitter is no longer offered via Fabric, so I'd
>   recommend migrating: dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/fabric Since Twitter
>   Kit 3 launched, you'd have a different init just for Twitter separate
>   from the Fabric init.